# What happened to the SAA1027?

Tags: stepper-motor

My electronics teacher asked me the other day to research the SAA 1027 to drive stepper motors however whats happened to them? In some newer textbooks they talk about using a PIC and then using a ULN2803 to drive it. Is this the new way as SAA 1027 are now obsolete?
Thanks in Advance,
Dean

Comment: I used a pair of these in the 80s to control a small robot. The 7.5V-18V for high matches matches the data sheet I had. I used [opto-isollators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opto-isolator) as I was connecting it up to an (expensive!) computer and this was the best way to achieve really good isolation. It's possible the requirement back then for a high degree of isolation meant providing the higher voltage wasn't so inconvenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I looked for the SAA1027 using findchips.com and it looks like no one has it.  According to this [datasheet from 13 years ago](http://www.sfu.ca/phys/430/datasheets/saa1027.pdf), The SAA 1027 can only provide 0.5 A output current and its inputs require inconvenient voltages: you have to provide it a voltage abpve 7.5 V for it to read as high!  This means it would be difficult to interface it with a modern microcontroller running at 3.3 or 5 V.

One modern, popular way of driving stepper motors is to use the A4983 IC.  It can provide up to 2 A of current per coil, perform microsteps, and it can easily interface with a microcontroller.

Pololu sells a convenient [carrier board](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1201) for it so you don't have to do SMT soldering yourself.  The reprap community uses this board a lot ([see here](http://reprap.org/wiki/Pololu_Electronics)).